# override CSS class only for a specific div?

Tags: css

The website is using Foundation as it's framework but for some reason in this form, if there are 2 columns, it is adding padding to the left and right on the 2 fields which means one row looks indented for no reason.

Is there a way for the div that wraps everything "form-wrapper" to reset the "columns" class padding?

Image here:

[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant "[mcve]" code to your question in order that those of us wanting to help can do so without visiting an external site.

Comment: You should try using `id` to identify specifically the div then use the css to that id (#id-name)

Comment: We cannot help you in any form with the information you told us. Please add some code sample or give us a url.

Comment: 1. it uses Foundation and 2 the only thing I'm asking about is how to get rid of padding on a specific div tag if possible. Why do you need "more information" - there's nothing else I need to know other than editing the padding out on a specific class "columns"

Comment: @kenfire Do you know the formatting for that? I've tried looking it up, but not getting anywhere.

Comment: @Daniel We need to see your code because that's how we help you. You asking us how to do something and not giving us the code is akin to running into a fellow programmer in the grocery store and asking "hey how would I do x" without any given context. The answer could be any of a dozen different things.

Comment: @TylerH - I understand this. However in this case, I'm just looking for how to remove padding on a class in a specific div without removing the padding for the whole site. I basically looking for some kind of CSS format.

Comment: @Daniel I understand, but if we tell you `.inputClass { padding: 0 }`, you will come back and say "tried that, it doesn't work", and we'll say "then there's something else giving it padding. **share your code**". Do you understand? We are trying to *avoid* guess work here.

Comment: Isn't there some format like: #theUniqueDiv .theSitewideClass{padding: none;} or something like that? I'm not looking for help, just need a something that will pick up the class when it comes in a div.

Comment: @Daniel Did any answer helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set an ID for the div you want to override and change it therefrom in css using the # selector.

Comment: Since it is using a CMS, there are plenty of divs and classes already surrounding this form. I'd like to just piggy back off one of them and say no padding on the columns class in one of them. If I reset the columns class now, it keeps doing it for the whole template.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood what I've written, if you set the ID for one element, it will only change the style for that element. It won't affect the others. Or perhaps I've misunderstood the question entirely? If so, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: the whole template uses a "columns" class throughout the entire site. I'm trying to find a div that contains this "columns" class and say "any .columns class in *this* div only - remove the padding" 

If it's not possible, then fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you:

```css
#my-id {
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-id">
  My div with padding
</div>
```

Just set the ID where you need.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a missing Foundation class that was needed. That's why it was difficult to figure out here.